# Keys are not detected in Xorg using xev

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-event

I have a new mechanical keyboard and I want to use some custom key build-in (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5).

The problem I encounter is that those keys are not detected in Xorg when I run `xev`.

I am able to see them when I run :

```
$ sudo showkey --keycodes                                                        
keycode 264 press
keycode 264 release
caught signal 2, cleaning up...
```

When I try to map the given keycode with `xmodmap`, for example, it does not work. Nothing happen when I press this key.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 264=a'
```

---

I suspect it might be because my keyboard is spitted in two virtual code keyboard (not sure why?)

```
$ xinput list                                                               
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius USB Optical Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mad Catz Mad Catz S.T.R.I.K.E.TE Mechanical Gaming Keyboard   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mad Catz Mad Catz S.T.R.I.K.E.TE Mechanical Gaming Keyboard   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

When I run `sudo evtest /dev/input/event2` "normal" key are detected but not those custom key.

And when I run `sudo evtest /dev/input/event3` "normal" key are not detected anymore but the custom one are, and output the same `keycodes` previously found using the `showkey` command.

---

I also tried to run `xev` from a clean X session but the result is the same...

Are there any other tests I can run, or other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

(1) X keycodes and kernel keycodes are not the same, you have to add 8 to the latter to get the former. Try it with `xev`, `showkey` and a normal letter, say <kbd>a</kbd>.

(2) If I remember correctly, keycodes greater than 256 are not supported under X.

So you need a custom kernel keyboard or HID mapping that maps your keycode `264` and the rest to other unused keycodes that are in the admissable range.

**Edit**

You can do this globally with `getkeycodes` resp. `setkeycodes`, or per device with the [udev hw database](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes), or per device using your own program with `EVIOCGKEYCODE_V2` and `EVIOCSKEYCODE_V2` ioctl's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of `(1)`, for me I add to add 9 but this still does not work with custom key. Any direction on how to custom keyboard or HID mapping ? Thanks again.